# How to store Array data into csv format file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array and I want to convert that array into a csv file here is my code and how i store my arrays :

```js
const words = ['item1','item2','item3']

const txtNumber = 2;
let newArr = []

for(let t= 1 ; t <= txtNumber ; t++) {
    const data = "item1 , item2 , item3 ,item4";
    const findWord = (word) => data.split(",").filter(x => x.includes(word))
    const array = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
        const x = findWord(words[i]);
        array.push(x[0])
    }
    newArr = array.map(x => x === undefined ? '' : x.trim());
    console.log(newArr)
}
```

how can i store newArr values into items.csv into my pc ?

Comment: The output of your code is a 1D Array, can you give an example of the desired output format? (is it rows or columns etc?)

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you might want `newArr.push()` instead of `newArr =` (as you are over-writing the previous results.)

Comment: yea i tried to make it work like this to store each array into a new line inside the csv file

Comment: @NickSlash the push function , is pushing the whole previous array into a single array which will make the whole array in a single line inside the csv file

Comment: My point was that after your code executes there is only one row in `newArr`, if each line is added to the CSV inside the `for` loop this is not an issue. If you could give provide an example of the output you desire it would make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im a little confused about what the desired output is, so no idea if this helps.

```
const fs = require('fs')
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.csv')

const words = ['item1','item2','item3']

const txtNumber = 2;
let newArr = []

for(let t= 1 ; t <= txtNumber ; t++) {
    const data = "item1 , item2 , item3 ,item4";
    const findWord = (word) => data.split(",").filter(x => x.includes(word))
    const array = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
        const x = findWord(words[i]);
        array.push(x[0])
    }
    newArr = array.map(x => x === undefined ? '' : x.trim());
    //console.log(newArr)
    writeStream.write(newArr.map(x=>`"${x}"`).join(",")+"\n")
}

writeStream.end()
```

The output of this should be (although I have not tested it)

```
"item1","item2","item3"
"item1","item2","item3"
```

Comment: yes this is what i needed , it stores the data into an array then save it inside a csv file ♥

Answer (score 0):

Store `newArr` values into `items.csv`

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const words = ['item1','item2','item3']

const txtNumber = 2;
let newArr = []

for(let t= 1 ; t <= txtNumber ; t++) {


const data = "item1 , item2 , item3 ,item4";
const findWord = (word) => data.split(",").filter(x => x.includes(word))

const array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
    const x = findWord(words[i]);
    array.push(x[0])
}
newArr = array.map(x => x === undefined ? '' : x.trim());


console.log(newArr)}





const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('items.csv');


writeStream.write(`item \n`);

writeStream.write('[ "' + newArr.join('","') + '" ]\n');
```

Comment: this one works but it only stores 1 row , i have 2 outputs and i want to store these 2 outputs into separate rows

Answer (score 0):

Super lazy solution would be, for example, this NPM package found at:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-array-to-csv

Disadvantage would be have an additional dependency to your project which you have no (or little) control over.